# When I search for user that does not exit in database I should get 404 error but it keeps getting 500. So why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, get-request

I should get 404 error but it keeps getting 500. So why?

```
app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id

  User.findById(_id).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send()
    }
    res.send(user)
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    res.status(500).send()
  })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried logging "e" to see what the error is and then fixing that first? try console.log(e); in your .catch() handler

Comment: Are you sure `req.params.id` contains a value?

Comment: when I change one letter req.params.id by another letter it works because I get 404. but when req.params.id is like 123 or abc I keep getting 500